# Spark Reading files from remote server

Tags: apache-spark

I have 1 node spark cluster and using WholeTextFile api or Textfile API to read and parse the files.

Can i know spark allow to read the files from remote server??? or the files physically needs to be present on Spark node.?

Comment: You'll want to look into Spark Streaming, but yes, remote file reading is possible.

Comment: can you give me an example for this while using binaryFiles API or WholeTextFile with JavaStreamingContext??

Answer (score 0):

You can read remote file with FTP

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkFiles
val filePath = "ftp://user:pwd/myhost/map/myinput.nt"
sc.addFile(filePath)
var fileName = SparkFiles.get(filePath.split("/").last)
var file = sc.textFile(fileName)
```

Comment: FTP means i am downloading the files to spark machine? If so, i need to delete them from spark machine after my work is done? Is my understanding correct??